# Ubuntu 16.04 after update today 27 Oct 2017, many strange behaviour on keyboard / pointer mouse

Tags: keyboard

Does anybody else having this problem, after having an update on Software Update today 20 Oct 2017. My ubuntu system are having lots of strange / annoying behaviour on keyboard / mouse or pointer..

There is couple of problem

1. The keyboard repeat is not working when i press n hold the key
2. The Alt + Tab just not working
3. When in terminal, i cannot scroll to the top, always come back down

All these problem sometimes occur, sometimes gone..
it is really annoying and i cannot work with these problem keep bugging me..

i am on lenovo laptop ideapad 500S btw.
anyhelp would be very appreciate